# Some Java Process objects finish and close, but some finish and stall

Tags: java, ffmpeg, process

My program uses `ProcessBuilder` to make various calls to ffmpeg.  My problem is that with certain commands I can create a `Process`, have it run, and when it is done it will terminate/exit/close itself and the program will end whereas other commands will run and create a finished output (in my case it will finish encoding a file with no corruption or anything at the end of the video), but won't close at which point I need to force terminate the program.  I have tested the ffmpeg commands that I am running in Windows Command Prompt and they all run fine without need for user input or anything.  I will show some examples of commands that do and don't work, but ultimately what I need is a way to tell why certain `Process`es do and don't work.  You probably don't even need to read the rest of this post if you know the inner workings of the `Process` class better than I do.

How I create my processes:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commandGoesHere);
Process p = pb.start();
p.waitFor();
```

Works:
`ffmpeg -i test.y4m -f segment -segment_times timecodeList .temp/sgmnt_%d.y4m`

This command takes a y4m(raw video format/large file size/1.7 GB for 53s of 720p video) and cuts it in to chunks.

Doesn't work (sometimes):
`ffmpeg -i chunkname.y4m outputName.mkv`

This command takes the chunked video and encodes it as h.264/AVC video.  When I create a process with this command it only works if the chunk is small in which case the `Process` will start, do its work, and close.

Doesn't work ever:
`ffmpeg -i test.mkv -c:v copy -f segment -segment_times timecodeList .temp/sgmnt_%d.mkv`

This command takes and h.264/AVC input video and cut it in to chunks, but this one doesn't terminate/exit/close when it's done.  I'm forced to terminate the program which I do after seeing the `Process`'s CPU utilization drop to 0% in Task Manager.  When I force terminate the program and check the output folder, all the chunks are there and not corrupted so I know it finished running successfully.

Comment: Have you tried supplying a `-nostdin` flag to `ffmpeg`? Afaik, it might misbehave sometimes when it's being piped with other programs because it expects some input from stdin and gets nothing or unexpected garbage.

Comment: @MikhailAntonov I tried it and no dice.  Frankly I didn't expect it to work since as far as I'm aware there is no piping occurring as a result of my program or as a result of how `Process` or `ProcessBuilder` work, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I've solved my problem.  I should have read the Javadoc for `Process` more thoroughly because it warned me of the problem there.  The Javadoc warns "Because some native platforms only provide limited buffer size for standard input and output streams, failure to promptly write the input stream or read the output stream of the subprocess may cause the subprocess to block, or even deadlock".  `ffmpeg` was printing out a lot to `stdout` and I wasn't doing anything to manage it.  Instead of managing it in Java I chose to add `-hide_banner` and `-loglevel error` to my command so that `ffmpeg` won't output anything to `stdout` unless it is an error.  In the future I can look in to a more comprehensive solution.